# Finding the value of y in a quadratic equation with a radical

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve for *y* and I am given the following:

$$\begin{cases}x^2 &= &y^3\\
(x-y)^2 &= &2x\end{cases}$$

So I expand that to get this:

$$x = y\sqrt{y}$$
$$y=\sqrt[3]{x^2}$$
$$x^2-2yx+y^2=2x$$

Now, since I am trying to solve for y, I rearranged the last equation to this:

$$y^3-2y*y\sqrt{y}+y^2=2*y\sqrt{y}$$
$$y^3-2y^2\sqrt{y}+y^2=2y\sqrt{y}$$
I could factor out some values, but I would not get to simplify it enough to use the quadratic formula:

$$y^2(y-2\sqrt{y}+1)=2y\sqrt{y}$$
$$y(y-2\sqrt{y}+1)=2\sqrt{y}$$

Where am I going to find y?

Comment: Why not just $y=x^{2/3}$?

Comment: @MPW Because $x$ is also unknown, I guess, hence this does not yield $y$.

Comment: @Did : Yes, I must have stopped reading the question after the first line. Didn't realize it was a system. I'm gonna edit and put in a brace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y^3 = x^2$ so $x= \pm y^{\frac 32}$.  But as $2x = (x-y)^2 \ge 0$ we may assume $x \ge 0$ and as $y^3 = x^2 \ge 0$ we may assume $y \ge 0$ so $y^{\frac 32} \ge 0$ and

$x = y^{\frac 32}$.

$x-y = y^{\frac 32} - y = y(\sqrt{y} - 1)$

$(x-y)^2 = y^2(y - 2\sqrt{y}+1) = 2x = 2y^{\frac 32}$

Either $y = 0$ and $x = 0^{\frac 32} = 0$ or $y \ne 0$.  If $y \ne 0$ then

$\sqrt{y}(y - 2\sqrt{y} + 1) = 2$

This *isnt* going to be solveable by a quadratic.

Let $t = \sqrt{y}$

$t(t-1)^2 = 2$

Note $t= 2$ is another solution.  $y = 4; x = 8$.  Are there any others?

Well, we are trying so solve $t(t-1)^2 = 2$ which is a 3rd degree equation.  So there may be to other solutions.

We have $t^3 - 2t^2 + t - 2 = 0$ is our equation.  You got lucky and saw that $t= 2$ was solution.  (We could have used the rational roots test to find it if we weren't so lucky).  So divide $t^3 - 2t^2 + t - 2$ by $t -2$.

We get $t^2 +1$.  Set that to zero and solve $t^2 + 1 = 0$ but that has no real solutions.

So $x=0; y = 0;$ and $x=8; y = 4$ are the only two real solutions.

If you want to find the complex solutions, we have $t = \pm i$ meaning $y = -1$ and $x^2 = -1$ so $x = \pm i$.

Thus our four solutions are $(0,0), (4, 8), (i, -1), (-i, -1)$.  Two are real, two are complex.

Comment: How do you get to $\sqrt{y}(y - 2\sqrt{y} + 1) = 2$. I get how you got $y^2(y - 2\sqrt{y}+1) = 2y^{\frac 32}$. But I don't know how you went from that to the next.

Comment: Divide both sides by $y^{3/2}$.

Comment: From $t^3 - 2t^2 + t - 2 = 0$ you did not find the solution 4 right, which means the only way you found 4 is by numerically trying?

Comment: No, I'd have been able to factor or use the rational root test.  But $t (t-1)^2=2$ had such a beautiful symmetry I just had to try t=2.  t-1=1.  I couldn't help myself.

Comment: I completely forgot t = 2, which is actually 4. Okay thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$y(y-2\sqrt y + 1)=2\sqrt y$$

gives

$$y^2-2y\sqrt y+y=2\sqrt y$$

$$y^2+y=2\sqrt y (y+1)$$

$$y(y+1)=2\sqrt y (y+1)$$

$$y=2\sqrt y$$

$$y^2=4y$$

Answer (score 1):

First, since you did "factor out,"  it implies that $y=0$ is a one of the solutions.

Next, consider your last derivation $y(y-2\sqrt{y}+1) = 2\sqrt{y}$, factor our once again, and denote $z = \sqrt{y}$ to obtain

$$z(z^2-2z+1) = 2,$$
or,
$$z^3 - 2z^2 + z -2=0,$$

Rewrite it as

$$z(z^2+1) - 2(z^2 +1) =0,$$

or,

$$(z^2+1)(z - 2) =0.$$

Hence,

$z=2$ is the solution, and replace it back to get $y=4$.

Answer (score 0):

from your first equation you will get
$$x=\pm\sqrt{y^3}=\pm y\sqrt{y}$$ we will solving the Problem for $+$:
plugging this in the second equation we will get
$$y^3+y^2=\sqrt{y}(2y+2y^2)$$
clearly $$y=0$$ is one solution, then we have
$$y^2+y=\sqrt{y}(2+2y)$$
suqaring we get
$$y^4+y^2+2y^3=y(4+4y^2+8y)$$
or
$$y^4-2y^3-7y^2-4y=0$$
or
$$y(y^3-2y^2-7y-4)=0$$
can you finish?